# Vue.js Bold terms from multiple search items

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am trying to allow a search that bold the parts that match. Example, if I have a name 'John' and search for 'Jo Joh' in the same string, I want it to take the part of john tha thas the most matches and bold that part, so it should come out like **Joh**n.

This is what I have so far, and I cant figure out why its saying "error during evaluation" in my vue tools debugger.

```
computed: {
    bold: function () {
        var compare = [];
        var word = 'john';
        var array = ['jo', 'joh'];

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (word.contains(array[i])) {
                compare[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
        var maxWord = compare[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < compare.length - 1; i++) {
            if (maxWord.length < compare[i].length) {
                maxWord = compare[i];
            }
        }
        return word.toString().replace(maxWord, '<strong>' + maxWord + '</strong>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [example](http://jsbin.com/zenixabala/edit?html,js,output). You can override the search input as you want.

There is a **boldString** method, what is convert the strings:

```
function boldString(str, find){
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>'+find+'</b>');
}
```

You can iterate over the array like this:

```
function search(input){
  var arr = ["john", "doe"];
  var res = "";
  var i = 0;
  while(i < arr.length) {
    res += boldString(arr[i], input);
    res += " "; 
    i++; 
  }
  return res;
}
```

I hope it helps!